# Searching for a parser or engine that can separate cities, country, product types and options from a query

Tags: c#

I have a need for a search engine that can parse a string into multiple sub-query (if that make sense).

Similar to those search engine where you can type `Casino in Las vegas` and it will retrieve the Casinos in Las Vegas.

I have to make a search engine that parse sentence like `B&B in Quebec with folding bed and breakfast` into

```
{
    type: { "B&B" },
    location: { "Quebec" },
    option: { "folding bed", "breakfast" }
}
```

So before I try to invent the wheel, I'd like to know if something like that exists in either open-source or commercial.

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/core/